# Change Heroku Postgres database column type while retaining data

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I've created a Heroku Postgres database, with one of the columns being `db.Integer` - storing integers. However, I realize that I should actually store floating point numbers instead - i.e., `db.Float`.

Can I change the type of a PostgreSQL database column - after it has been created with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use following query to do that:

```sql
ALTER TABLE $TABLE_NAME ALTER COLUMN $COLUMN_NAME TYPE <float type, e.g. float(64)>;
```